# Serving static assets for a single-page-app with nginx

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, static-site

I'm trying to figure out how to have nginx serve static assets, have a fallback to index.html, and forward to the API.
Currently, all I have working is the root route `/`, and the API forwarding.

This is the behavior that I'm after:

```
GET /          -> nginx sends s3/index.html (current)
* /api         -> nginx proxies to the puma server (current)

# Yet to figure out (and the reason for this question)
GET /sub-route    -> nginx sends s3/index.html, and routing is handled by the js framework
GET *.css|.js|etc -> nginx forwards to the s3 bucket (all relative to index.html)
```

---

Here is my nginx.conf (it has some template things in it, cause (as part of the deploy process) I do:

```
envsubst '$S3_BUCKET:$NGINX_PORT' < /app/deployment/nginx.template.conf > /app/deployment/nginx.conf
```

---

```
pid        /app/tmp/nginx.pid;

events {  }
http {
  upstream puma {
    server unix:///app/sockets/puma.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen ${NGINX_PORT} default_server deferred;
    server_name aeonvera.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    root /app/public;
    access_log /app/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /app/log/nginx.error.log info;

    client_max_body_size 20M;
    keepalive_timeout 5;


    location ~ ^/api {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://puma;
    }

    # Send all other requests to the index.html
    # stored up on s3
    location / {
      # tell all URLs to go to the index.html
      # I got an error with this about having proxy_pass within a location...?
      # location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2|woff|ttf)$ {
      #   proxy_pass "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${S3_BUCKET}/ember/"
      #
      #   gzip_static on;
      #   expires max;
      #   add_header Cache-Control public;
      # }

      # Don't know what this does
      rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

      # only ever GET these resources
      limit_except GET {
        deny all;
      }


      # use google as dns
      resolver 8.8.8.8;

      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_set_header       Host 's3.amazonaws.com';
      proxy_set_header       Authorization '';

      # avoid passing along amazon headers
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-delete-marker;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-version-id;

      # cookies are useless on these static, public resources
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
      proxy_set_header cookie "";

      proxy_buffering        off;

      # s3 replies with 403 if an object is inaccessible; essentially not found
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      # error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

      # the actual static files
      proxy_pass             "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${S3_BUCKET}/ember/index.html";
    }

  }
}
```

#### Update 1

I've added this above `location /`

```
location ~ ^/(assets|fonts) {
  rewrite (.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${S3_BUCKET}/ember";

  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

but it gives an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /app/deployment/nginx.conf:53
```

The thinking behind this change, is that since all my assets are in known locations, I could tell nginx to proxy to that location, and then have a `rewrite (.*) / permanent;` for my `location /`

#### Update 2

I thought maybe I could re-write the url for `/dashboard`,
so that nginx would proxy_pass the index.html. No success.

```
  rewrite ^/(.*) / break;
  proxy_pass             "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${S3_BUCKET}/ember/index.html";
```

That just redirects to s3's marketing page

```
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 08 Feb 2018 13:22:49 GMT
Location:https://aws.amazon.com/s3/
Server:nginx/1.12.0
```

Response Headers ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I figured it out, but It'd be super helpful if someone could verify, as I'm still fairly new to nginx.

```
location / {
  # ...

  proxy_set_header       Host 's3.amazonaws.com';

  # ...

  rewrite ^/(.*) /${S3_BUCKET}/ember/index.html break;
  proxy_pass             "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${S3_BUCKET}/ember/index.html";
}
```

Having the `Host` header is important here, because without it, rewrite will change the URL in the user's browser (which we don't want to do, cause that will more than likely mess with the SPA's routing.